# How to transfer wordpress hosting website to CDN?

Tags: wordpress, hosting, web-hosting, cdn, web-development-server

I have wordpress hosting websites and now I want to it transfer to CDN.How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of plugins that can automatically do this for you. For example CloudFlare: https://wordpress.org/plugins/cloudflare/

Also see: http://www.wpexplorer.com/free-cdn-services-for-wordpress/

(note: these CDN services do not host the site but cache the site and load it from a closer server)